# How can I observe array changes and see which new element is added?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

```
onArrayChanged: function(obj, keyName, value) {

    // What is value here, exactly?

}.property('array.@each')
```

When an element is added to the array, how do I know which value was added? LIkewise, when a value is removed from the array, how do I access that?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Have a look at [addArrayObserver](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/master/packages/ember-runtime/lib/mixins/array.js#L214-251), see http://jsfiddle.net/pangratz666/EE65Z/:

```js
var a = Ember.A('a b c d e f g'.w());

var o = Ember.Object.create({
    arrayWillChange: Ember.K,
    arrayDidChange: function(array, start, removeCount, addCount) {
        console.log(arguments);
    }
});

a.addArrayObserver(o);
```