# When observing elements of an array with @each, how can I know which elements are being added or removed?

Tags: ember.js

The subject says it all. I'm observing changes in a property of the elements of an array:

```
onChange: function() {
  //
}.observes(content.@each.selected)
```

and I'd like to know exactly which elements are being added and removed. After a few experiments, I found out that I can add three parameters to the observing function, but none of them are the elements being added/removed.

Is there an easier solution than keeping a copy of the array and then doing a manual comparison with the new one?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I observe array changes and see which new element is added?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10390050/how-can-i-observe-array-changes-and-see-which-new-element-is-added)

Answer (score 0):

You can store the content before it changes and compare it with the content after the change:

```
willChange: function() {
  this.contentBeforeSelectedChange = this.get('content').slice(0);
}.observesBefore('content.@each.selected')

onChange: function() {
  var content = this.get('content');
  var oldContent = this.contentBeforeSelectedChange.toArray();

  var whichChanged = content.find(function(item, index){
     var oldItem = oldContent[index].get('selected');
     return item.get('selected') !== oldItem.get('selected');
  });
}.observes(content.@each.selected)
```

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm doing right now (I mentioned this in my question) but I was hoping there would be an easier way since Ember knows which elements are being added or removed from the array...