# Find out which individual item changed in an Ember ArrayController

Tags: javascript, ember.js, observers

In an `Ember.ArrayController`, I have a function that `.observes()`
a property  on the entire array of the model for a property change.

```
var FoosController = Ember.ArrayController.extend(Ember.Evented, {

    observesEachFooBar: function() {
        var foos = this.get('model');
        foos.forEach(function(foo) {
            //test if this foo has changed, then do something
        });
    }.observes('model.@each.bar'),

});
```

Here I am manually testing every single  `Foo` in its model.
How can I avoid doing this, and just be given the individual one (or few)
that have changed?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I observe array changes and see which new element is added?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10390050/how-can-i-observe-array-changes-and-see-which-new-element-is-added)

Comment: @SteveH. That does not quite apply - the difference being that array observers look for changes to the array itself (addition and removal of elements). However, what I am asking for is observing properties of the array's elements.

Comment: @SteveH. Put another way, the question that you have linked may be a solution for `.observes('model.@each')` but is **not** a solution for `.observes('model.@each.bar')`

Comment: Use case? Observing every possibly property is generally a bad idea for pretty obvious reasons.

Comment: I should say that observing all possible properties on large collections is probably a bad idea. Probably fine on small collections. :)

Comment: @MatthewBlancarte Yeah, agreed. In my case I am only observing a single property on every object in an array (whose size would typically be less than twenty). The actual number of observers that are needed, therefore, should be quite manageable.

Comment: Oh yeah you are good to go. I've had this sort of feature bite me before so I have a knee-jerk paranoid reaction when I see it. :) Once bitten, twice shy or something like that.

Answer (score 2):

Ember does this with the SortableMixin.  You can follow the same pattern.

https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/v1.6.1/packages_es6/ember-runtime/lib/mixins/sortable.js#L247

```
        forEach(sortProperties, function(sortProperty) {
          addObserver(item, sortProperty, this, 'contentItemSortPropertyDidChange');
        }, this);
      }, this);
    }

    return this._super(array, idx, removedCount, addedCount);
  },

  insertItemSorted: function(item) {
    var arrangedContent = get(this, 'arrangedContent');
    var length = get(arrangedContent, 'length');

    var idx = this._binarySearch(item, 0, length);
    arrangedContent.insertAt(idx, item);
  },

  contentItemSortPropertyDidChange: function(item) {
    var arrangedContent = get(this, 'arrangedContent'),
        oldIndex = arrangedContent.indexOf(item),
        leftItem = arrangedContent.objectAt(oldIndex - 1),
        rightItem = arrangedContent.objectAt(oldIndex + 1),
        leftResult = leftItem && this.orderBy(item, leftItem),
        rightResult = rightItem && this.orderBy(item, rightItem);

    if (leftResult < 0 || rightResult > 0) {
      arrangedContent.removeObject(item);
      this.insertItemSorted(item);
    }
  },
```

Comment: Essentially what OP was trying to avoid, but hey, great lesson in reading the source. +1

Comment: @ kingpin2k yeah, this would simply be adding observers to each item in the array individually. It will work, but I was hoping that there was a way to accomplish this using declarative syntax, similar to `.observes('model.@each.propertyName')`.

Comment: Yeah, that's the only available pattern where you can accomplish this.  On the plus side if performance is really an issue this would be the way to go, you loop once on setting up the observer, then on change that exact item is sent to the callback instead of having to loop each time an item changes.  So you pay the price up front, for cheaper calls later.

Answer (score 0):

**[Here is an example](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/ceculo/3/edit)** using the `addArrayObserver` method, along with `arrayContentWillChange` and `arrayContentDidChange`.

```
App.IndexController = Em.ArrayController.extend({
  initializer: function() {
    this.addArrayObserver({
      arrayWillChange: Em.K,
      arrayDidChange: function(observedObj, start, removeCount, addCount) {
        if(!removeCount && !addCount) {
          alert('Array item at ' +start+ ' updated');
        }
      }
    });
  }.on('init'),

  actions: {
    updateData: function() {
      this.get('content').arrayContentWillChange(3, 0, 0);
      this.set('content.3.foo', 'foo3-updated');
      this.get('content').arrayContentDidChange(3, 0, 0);
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: I don't see any use in setting up the array observer here, you're manually triggering the events.  You might as well just create two methods and call them any time you want to change the data.

Comment: @kingpin2k I get your point. This just an alternative solution. The OP didn't want to check every item to check which item changed. That said, I need to look into what these `arrayContentWillChange` and `arrayContentDidChange` are really used for.